# Custom Autocomplete control in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create autocomplete control shown in below image in reactjs. Basically it is autocomplete control with two section one is static and another one is dynamic. Dynamic section loads data from the ajax call. I would like to know if any available autocomplete control provides this functionality. If not then I have to create my own custom control. So I would like to know any good example or reusable code which I can use to implement this control.

[image]

Comment: There are several autocomplete components available for react. I've used Material-ui's component and it serves me well. You can add the static part as some static html and show it beside the auto-complete suggestions. It does not  need to lie inside the auto-complete suggestions' component.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend this dependency: [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) .
I have used it on a few projects, and it offers you easy styling customization and easy customization of React code by providing you possibility to add your custom components.

If you take a look at this [example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/CustomComponents.js), you can get a basic overview on how to apply your custom component to react-select.

You will need to create your custom component that will look like your image but react-select will take care for other things for you and offer you easy customization.